# pop up from linkl

Tags: php

I have a link that I would like to open a page in a pop up, the link and onclick work fine but open it in a new full window but when I add the part after '_blank' it stops working.  Here's my code

```
echo '<li>'.$img.'<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'job_detail.php?id='.$item_id.'\'_blank\', \'toolbar=0,location=no,menubar=0,height=550,width=500,left=200, top=300\')">'.$item_name.'</a></li>';
```

I suspect there is a typo or a problem with my syntax but I can't find it.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<li>'.$img.'<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'job_detail.php?id='.$item_id.'\', \'_blank\', \'toolbar=0,location=no,menubar=0,height=550,width=500,left=200, top=300\')">'.$item_name.'</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<li>'.$img.'<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'job_detail.php?id='.$item_id.'\', \'_blank\', \'toolbar=0,location=no,menubar=0,height=550,width=500,left=200, top=300\')">test'.$item_name.'</a></li>';
```

Comment: hi, thanks but it doesn't open it in a pop up, it opens it as a full window

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some closing single quotes in the window.open arguments, and the arguments you are passing are slightly incorrect. _blank is a separate argument from URL (the first argument,) URL needs a closing single quote, and NAME needs an opening single quote. corrected code is below

```
echo('<li>' . $img . '<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'job_detail.php?id=' . $item_id . '\',\'_blank\', \'toolbar=0,location=no,menubar=0,height=550,width=500,left=200,top=300\')">' . $item_name . '</a></li>');
```